# ImportError: Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed (python3.4)?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

l stuck with this error please help. l'm on ubuntu python3.4 how  can l install pygtk package ?

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 16, in 
    raise ImportError("Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.")
ImportError: Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed